# Class Diagram reversed engineered?

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

I recently worked with UModel 2010 to generate a Class Diagram from my Visual Studio 2010 C# project.
I have to admit, apart from crappy placement, it worked great (for me)!
problem is, my trial licence is expired, so I would like to know if someone has a nice and free alternative.
I only need to reverse engineer the class diagram from my sourcecode.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [startUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) tool to reverse engineer. StarUML is open source.

If you are looking for a temporary tool then you an also look at [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) which has support for reverse engineering. It gives a 30 day trial period.

Comment: Thanks, I tried StarUML, but couldnt find a way to reverse engineer. When I did, StarUML fails to make a ClassDiagram from all my files (Status:failed at the reverse engineering overview)